Using must in the past
1 "I think you must help her" vs 2 "I think you must be a cook"
First implies obligation that's why in the past it should be like this "I thought you had to help her". The other depending on a tone could be either deduction or obligaton, so we would either leave "must" unchanged if it is deduction and change it into "had to" if it was obligation? Is that correct?

must has no marked past tense and so to indicate past obligation a periphrastic form is an option, such as "had to" or "were obliged to" or "needed to".  With necessity arising from deduction, "were obliged to" doesn't work, of course, so "had to" is the best choice there.

@TimR so with a periphrastic I could leave "must" unchanged either it implies deduction or obligation?

Sorry, I don't know what you're asking. Please rephrase the question.

"You must give me that tomorrow" and now "He said that I must give him that the next day". That is fine or do I need to ues "had to"?

When did he say this?  Before today or today?

before today ..

Clearest would be "He said that I had to give it to him the following day."  (or the next day)


The correspondences between these terms and obligation vs. deduction aren't airtight. People will say things like "That guy has to be Ryan Gosling!" and mean that they've deduced it. That said, "must" is not used very often for obligation in everyday speech, because it sounds pretentious.


"You must hand this in to me by 8 a.m.," said the stuffy old teacher.


In modern English, a bare "must" as preterite is essentially unheard-of. I've seen an instance where an English literature professor mistook Jane Austen's use of it as the present (in their introduction to the novel!), and I've met other well-educated English speakers who didn't know that it was once used thus.

However, we do use "must" in the perfect: "That guy must have been Ryan Gosling." This is indeed only for deduction. But just as with (1) above, we could also say "That guy had to be Ryan Gosling" or "That guy had to have been Ryan Gosling" and mean deduction.

For past obligation, we do typically use "had to" — or else a variant based on the nature of the obligation ("was asked to", "was expected to", etc).



"You must give me that tomorrow"  and now "He said that I must give him that the next day". That is fine or do I need to ues "had to"?

@marta If "the next day" was in the past, use "had to". If it's in the future, use "have to".
